# PHP: Alternate Display

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system

I was hoping someone could help with a conundrum. I am using substr to give an abstract of articles. Now the problem is when you click the link to see the whole article you still see the substr version. Now this obviously happens because of the way the code is. But can anyone help with an alternative so when you click the link you can see the full article?

```
<?php
class MyCMS 
{
function get_content($id = "")
{
    if ($id != ""):
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE blog_id = '$id'";
        $return = '<p><a href="index.php"> Go Back To Content Page</a></p>';

    else:
        $sql = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
    endif;

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) !=0):
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
            echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
            echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more </div>";
        }
        else:
            echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
            echo $return;
        endif;  

}


}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of tackling this in php it might be better to use css's text-overflow:ellispse on the article container.

Comment: Or use 2 queries and one which handles the abstract using SQL alone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are doing two different things with one script and one function . You should make two separate scripts and two functions. This way it would be easier to understand what's happening. Something like :

```
class MyCMS 
{
   function get_content($id)
   {

        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE blog_id = '$id'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($res) !=0) {
           //display the content of the article
        } else {
           //ooops that article does not exist, link to index.php
        }
    }


    function getLinks()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
        if(mysql_num_rows($res) !=0){
           while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
              //see : href="article.php ...  !
              echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="article.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
              echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
              echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more </div>";
           }

        }
    }
}
```

and then two pages

**index.php**

```
//getLinks
```

**article.php**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
//get_content($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you validate your code like below ?? The code I'm ging to write has a good structure that what you are currently doing.

please consider the code below

```
<?php

class MYCMS{


function get_content($id=""){


if(is_numeric($id) && ($id!=""){

//no  validation required because id can only be a number and could not be blank //

$sql = "SELECT blog_id, title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";



if(mysql_num_rows($sql)< 1){

//show message if no article is found //

echo '<p> UH OOH! THERE IS NO SUCH PAGE IT DOES\'T EXIST </p>'; 
            echo $return;


}




else{

//If article is found //


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))

        {
            echo '<div id="roundedbox"><h2><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['blog_id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . ' </a></h2>';
            echo '<div id="date"><h5><p>' . $row['date'] . '</p></h5></div>';
            echo substr('<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p>',0, 90)." .... "." read more </div>";
        }


}

//




}

// If id is not numeric or blank //

else{    $return = '<p><a href="index.php"> Go Back To Content Page</a></p>';      }


}



}


?>
```